# Altering variable's value in a function by calling another function as a subfunction

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, while-loop

```
def tim():
    cash = 100
    while cash != 0:
        print("while loop:",cash)
        john(cash)

def john(cash):
    print("john func:",cash)
    cash = cash -1

tim()
```

Can someone explain why john() does not reduce the value of cash? I've been struggling with this for quite long.

Comment: because `cash` is a local variable, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard im writing a betting game where cash is increasing or decreasing while it is still not 0. How should I implement this?

Comment: Okay, why do you need an additional function to do the increasing and decreasing?

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I assumed it was bad practice to have functions that have codes that are too long so I wrote another function to be called within it

Comment: Well, sure, but you took it to the extreme. Just use `cash` in `tim`.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Do u mind taking a look at my code, and suggest how should I structure them. https://paste.ofcode.org/yCdLt39zJD5hhQeHj46kVs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158554/discussion-between-xuan-and-jim-fasarakis-hilliard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function parameters are passed by value, not by reference, so assigning to the variable in `john` has no effect on the variable in `tim`. The function should return the new value:

```
def tim():
    cash = 100
    while cash != 0:
        print("while loop:",cash)
        cash = john(cash)

def john(cash):
    print("john func:",cash)
    return cash - 1

tim()
```